# I am facing a error ReferenceError: Paginator is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I was making a app and this paginator was a screen but when i am rendering it is giving me a error I am facing a error ReferenceError: Paginator is not defined

```
export default Paginator = ({data}) => {
return (
<View>
<Text>Hi</Text>
</View>
);
}
```

Comment: How do you import Paginator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it like this

```
const Paginator = ({data}) => {
return (
<View>
<Text>Hi</Text>
</View>
);
}


export default Paginator
```